# Do something if no arguments present

Tags: ruby

This is a small test script I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby


require 'packetfu'


def mac(host)

    if host
      rmac = PacketFu::Utils.arp(host, :iface => 'wlan0')
      puts rmac
    else  
      whoami = PacketFu::Utils.whoami?(:iface => 'wlan0')
      puts whoami
    end
end

mac(ARGV[0])
```

What I want to do is have it print the second variable if no argument is specified. Instead I get an ArgumentError. There's obviously an easier way that I'm just missing.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to call the function without any arguments, you need to change its definition to such that it does not require an argument. One way is to give the argument a default value. Then you can check for that, e.g.,

```
def mac(host = nil)
  if host
    puts "host: #{host}"
  else
    puts 'no host'
  end
end
```

If you want to distinguish between no argument given and argument given with the default value, you could use a variable number of arguments:

```
def mac2(*args)
  if args.empty?
    puts "no arguments"
  else
    host = args[0]
  end
end
```

On the other hand, if your problem is detecting whether `ARGV` was empty (i.e., no *command-line* argument given), you can check that higher up. For example, only call `mac` if an argument was given:

```
if ARGV.empty?
  puts "Usage: …"
  exit 1
end
mac(ARGV[0])
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been clearer. Your code almost works, but I get this error specifically: str is not a valid IPV4 address (ArgumentError), when I don't enter in an IP address.

Comment: Please clarify.  What is the statement that raises that exception?

Comment: Based on the code you posted, the same error HAS TO occur even if you enter an ip address, which means you aren't calling those packetfu methods correctly.

Comment: @user3408678 Note that your code calls the two `PacketFu` methods without checking `host`. You need to move the calls to the then-branch of `if host` or something similar, otherwise the missing `host` causes the error…